# Spinner is not showing the selected value when I fetch data from MySql database

Tags: java, android, mysql, spinner

I have created a project in which I am using spinner.
In spinner I am setting data fetched from MySql database. The data is being fetched properly as I can get the whole in the dropdown.
The problem is that spinner is not showing the selected value in the text area.

When I tested it with another arraylist of strings which was created in the program it was working.
I don't know why it is not working properly with the data fetched from database.

Kindly help me if you know the solution.

The java file is here when I used the data from MySql database

```
package com.help.adminpasskart;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class addSubCategory extends AppCompatActivity {
ImageView categoryImageView , categoryImageBtn;
TextView categoryNameView ;
Button confirmBtn;
String categoryimg;

Spinner genderDrop , categoryDrop;
ArrayList<String> genders = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<>();

private final String url = "http://passkart.online/Z_addCategory.php";
private final String url2 = "http://passkart.online/Z_getGender.php";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_sub_category);

    categoryImageView = findViewById(R.id.addcategoryimageView);
    categoryImageBtn = findViewById(R.id.addcategoryimagebtn);
    categoryNameView = findViewById(R.id.addcategorynameView);
    confirmBtn = findViewById(R.id.addCategoryConfirmBtn);
    genderDrop = findViewById(R.id.genderDropDown);
    categoryDrop = findViewById(R.id.categoryDropDown);

    getGenders();
    

    ArrayAdapter<String> myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(addSubCategory.this,         
    R.layout.droptextlayout,genders);
    myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    genderDrop.setAdapter(myAdapter);

    
    genderDrop.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long     
   id) {
            String item = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
            Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "Selected: " + item, 
   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            genderDrop.setSelection(position);


        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });

}



public void getGenders(){

    StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url2, new 
   Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            try {
                JSONObject Jobject = new 
   JSONObject(response.substring(response.indexOf("{"), response.lastIndexOf("}") + 1));
                String success = Jobject.getString("success");
                JSONArray Jarray = Jobject.getJSONArray("datas");
                if(success.equals("1")) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < Jarray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject object = Jarray.getJSONObject(i);
                        String name = object.getString("name");

                        genders.add(name);
                    }
                }

            } catch (JSONException jsonException) {
                jsonException.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }


    });

    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(addSubCategory.this);
    queue.add(request);
};

 }
```

The java file is here when I used the arraylist created in the program.In this code the spinner is working fine

```
package com.help.adminpasskart;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class addSubCategory extends AppCompatActivity {
ImageView categoryImageView , categoryImageBtn;
TextView categoryNameView ;
Button confirmBtn;
String categoryimg;

Spinner genderDrop , categoryDrop;
ArrayList<String> genders = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<>();

private final String url = "http://passkart.online/Z_addCategory.php";
private final String url2 = "http://passkart.online/Z_getGender.php";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_sub_category);

    categoryImageView = findViewById(R.id.addcategoryimageView);
    categoryImageBtn = findViewById(R.id.addcategoryimagebtn);
    categoryNameView = findViewById(R.id.addcategorynameView);
    confirmBtn = findViewById(R.id.addCategoryConfirmBtn);
    genderDrop = findViewById(R.id.genderDropDown);
    categoryDrop = findViewById(R.id.categoryDropDown);

    getGenders();
    
    words.add("word1");
    words.add("word2");
    words.add("word3");
    words.add("word4");
    words.add("word5");
    words.add("word6");
    words.add("word7");
    words.add("word8");
    words.add("word9");
    words.add("word10");



    ArrayAdapter<String> myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(addSubCategory.this,         
    R.layout.droptextlayout,words);
    myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    genderDrop.setAdapter(myAdapter);

    
    genderDrop.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long     
   id) {
            String item = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
            Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "Selected: " + item, 
   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            genderDrop.setSelection(position);


        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });

}



public void getGenders(){

    StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url2, new 
   Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            try {
                JSONObject Jobject = new 
   JSONObject(response.substring(response.indexOf("{"), response.lastIndexOf("}") + 1));
                String success = Jobject.getString("success");
                JSONArray Jarray = Jobject.getJSONArray("datas");
                if(success.equals("1")) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < Jarray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject object = Jarray.getJSONObject(i);
                        String name = object.getString("name");

                        genders.add(name);
                    }
                }

            } catch (JSONException jsonException) {
                jsonException.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }


    });

    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(addSubCategory.this);
    queue.add(request);
};

 }
```

MySql file is here

```
<?php
include "config.php";

   $sql="SELECT * FROM `$db`.`genderCategory`";
   $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
   $categories['datas'] = array();
   if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){
       while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
           $data['id']=$row['0'];
        $data['name']= $row['1'];
        $data['image']=$row['2'];

       
        array_push($categories['datas'],$data);
       }

       $categories['success']='1';
       echo json_encode($categories);
        mysqli_close($conn);
    }else{ 
        echo "No gender added";

    }
    ?>
```

Comment: And the mysql part?

Comment: I have attached my MySql file . Kindly check it out now. @JavierG.Raya

Answer (score 0):

Finally , I have solved it by myself
The problem was that the method getGenders() was not getting the arrayAdapter
So , I defined it inside the method and booyah !!  My problem got solved .

```
public class addSubCategory extends AppCompatActivity {
ImageView categoryImageView , categoryImageBtn;
TextView categoryNameView ;
Button confirmBtn;
Spinner genderDrop , categoryDrop;
ArrayList<String> genders = new ArrayList<>();

ArrayAdapter<String> myAdapter;

private final String url2 = "http://passkart.online/Z_getGender.php";

String gender ;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_sub_category);

    categoryImageView = findViewById(R.id.addcategoryimageView);
    categoryImageBtn = findViewById(R.id.addcategoryimagebtn);
    categoryNameView = findViewById(R.id.addcategorynameView);
    confirmBtn = findViewById(R.id.addCategoryConfirmBtn);
    genderDrop = findViewById(R.id.genderDropDown);
    categoryDrop = findViewById(R.id.categoryDropDown);

    getGenders();
    
   genderDrop.setOnItemSelectedListener(new 
    AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int 
     position, long id) {
            myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            String item = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
            genderDrop.setSelection(position);
            gender = item;
        }
        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        }
    });
   
}



public void getGenders(){

    StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url2, 
   new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            try {
                JSONObject Jobject = new 
   JSONObject(response.substring(response.indexOf("{"), 
    response.lastIndexOf("}") + 1));
                String success = Jobject.getString("success");
                JSONArray Jarray = Jobject.getJSONArray("datas");
                if(success.equals("1")) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < Jarray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject object = Jarray.getJSONObject(i);
                        String name = object.getString("name");

                        genders.add(name);
                    }
     //Array adapter is defined here ..........

                    myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String> (addSubCategory.this, R.layout.droptextlayout,genders);
                    myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    genderDrop.setAdapter(myAdapter);
                }

            } catch (JSONException jsonException) {
                jsonException.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }

    });

    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(addSubCategory.this);
    queue.add(request);
  };
 }
```

I am posting this answer for those who are still dealing with this error.